# Handling JSON on server-side

Tags: android, json

I want to send data from my Android app to my server.
On the client-side, meaning the application,I can create the JSON object and send it to the server.
The problem is, I don't know how to 'handle' it on the server side.All I want my server to do is to receive the JSON, parse it, and show it to me.That's it.

I know it's pretty vague question, but I don't really know where to start here, and would love if anyone could show me a complete tutorial.

Thanks!

Comment: What server-side language(s) are you using?

Comment: To be honest I don't have any experience in working with server-side languages. All I need is to be able to receive the JSON and parse it.Was hoping you could show me a complete example of how this can be done.Thanks

Comment: Then the very first step is to pick a server-side language (and probably library/framework as well) to work with.

Comment: PhP would be nice.But I can't find any tutorials that covers this topic completely.I don't want to learn php or asp.net, but to simply perform this one 'mission'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP and json_decode() 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Here a quick example how to handle the data:

```
        // get json
        $input = json_decode($_GET["json"]);

        // get values
        $firstname = $input->firstName;
        $surename = $input->lastName;
        $age = intval($input->age);

        // check values
        if (isset($firstname) && !empty($firstname) && 
            isset($surename) && !empty($surename) &&
            isset($age) && is_numeric($age))
        {
            // do something
            echo "Hello ".htmlspecialchars($firstname)." ".htmlspecialchars($surename)."!<br>";
            echo "You are $age years old! Wow.";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Some values are missing or incorrect";
        }
```

I used the GET parameter in this example. If you have larger data, use POST instead of GET.

Example:
URL: http://localhost/test/index.php?json={ "firstName" : "John","lastName" : "Doe","age" : 23 }
Output: Hello John Doe!
You are 23 years old! Wow.

But: Make sure you encode the JSON data at your application. In my example the browser does it.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I receive the String that I have sent from my app?

Comment: I've added a short example using GET. Hope this is helpfull

Answer (score 0):

```
// Some groovy code to dump an incoming request
import com.sun.net.httpserver.*;
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(2228),0)
server.createContext('/', { HttpExchange exchange ->
    println 'got a request'
    println 'requestHeaders '+exchange.requestHeaders
    println 'requestBody '+exchange.requestBody.text
    exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200,0);
    exchange.responseBody.write('hello from groovy land.'.bytes)
    exchange.responseBody.close();
    println 'all done'
}  as HttpHandler)
server.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use some shell script CGI file on the server. Here's a sample returning some fixed data to a JSONP request for testing something.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Handle a JSONP request for data returning a fake queue status result.

read -r -d '' DATA <<'EOF'
{
 name: "TESTHOST",
 status: "running",
 items: [
  {id:"4",status:"failed",title:"anadin map 2",user:"pat",progress:100},
  {id:"2",status:"running",title:"silicon map",user:"tim",progress:52},
  {id:"3",status:"queued",title:"anadin map",user:"pat",progress:0},
  {id:"6",status:"queued",title:"neon calibration",user:"ian",progress:0}
 ]
}
EOF

CB=$(echo $QUERY_STRING | sed -n 's/.*jsoncallback=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p')
DATA=${DATA/52/$(expr $RANDOM % 100)}
DATA="${CB}(${DATA});"
echo -e "content-type: application/json\r"
echo -e "content-length: ${#DATA}\r"
echo -e "x-test: $CB\r"
echo -e "\r"
echo "$DATA"
```

Substitute some parsing of the request data and return as appropriate.